# Python 3 Selenium fails to execute javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm using python 3 and I'm using Selenium to try to scrape data off a website. I need to remove a class from a list item in order to display the data I need, this is the code:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('otherClassName isSelected').classList.remove('isSelected');")
```

but I get the error

> "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined"

I have also tried

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('otherClassName isSelected').setAttribute('class', 'otherClassName')")
```

but then I get

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: document.getElementsByClassName(...).setAttribute is not a function

Comment: Your script is most probably wrong and thats is why selenium is giving you an error. Launch the browser developer console and execute this JS in console. Once it runs over there then check it in selenium

Comment: Good idea, I found out the problem this way and answered my question. Thank you @TarunLalwani

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because you're trying to apply class name update for *multiple* elements at once while `setAttribute()` allows to apply changes to one element at the time.

Try below code instead

```
js = """document.querySelectorAll('.otherClassName.isSelected')
    .forEach( x=> x.setAttribute("class","otherClassName"));"""
driver.execute_script(js)
```

P.S. It seem to be [*XY problem*](http://xyproblem.info/) as usually you don't need to make changes to page source while page scraping. You should share more details about your initial problem

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to add [0] after getting the element by class, so the correct code should be:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('otherClassName isSelected')[0].classList.remove('isSelected');")
```